# What is causing this unwanted lip when I apply a subdivision surface?

Tags: modeling

I'm following the blender guru's donut tutorial, and I somehow split the object into "two groups?". Once I apply the subdivision surface modifier, a weird lip is overhanging at the top. Obviously I could just remodel the donut, but I would like to know how I can undo this for future knowledge. Detailed images below.
[image] Object mode: [image] Selected in wireframe: [image] After subdivision and modifier settings:[image][image]

Comment: maybe check if you don't have inverted normals, or overlapping vertices

Comment: Hmmm, the normals and vertices look fine.

Comment: Maybe you've duplicated the top for icing, and it's still there, showing more in subdiv. .. part of the same object?

Comment: it looks like a separate mesh, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/e101f264d21d4d0f8402eac7f2121621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 meshes within the same object, press <kbd>L</kbd> to select the top mesh, and move it. You can keep it, if you want to separate it press <kbd>P</kbd>:

[image]

Also, increase the *Clip Start* a bit if you want to avoid display glitches:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!